# Problema notas e moedas

Tags: c, c++

A questão dada exigia que usasse scanf para ler um certo valor em ponto flutuante de 0 a 1000000 e printasse quantas cédulas de 100, 50,20,10, 5 reais e 2 reais, e quantas moedas de 1 real, 50,25,10,5,1 centavo teriam o valor inserido. O código está lendo e printando os valores corretamente, mas a plataforma não aceita o código.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
int main (){
    int valor1,valor2;
    int count_100=0,count_50=0,count_20=0,count_10=0,count_5=0,count_2=0;
    int count_50cents=0,count_1=0,count_25cents=0,count_10cents=0,count_5cents=0,count_1cents=0;
scanf("%f",&valor);
while(valor>=100){
    valor=valor-100;
    count_100++;
}
while(valor>=50){
    valor=valor-50;
    count_50++;
}
while(valor>=20){
    valor=valor-20;
    count_20++;
}
while(valor>=10){
    valor=valor-10;
    count_10++;
}
while(valor>=5){
    valor=valor-5;
    count_5++;
}
while(valor>=2){
    valor=valor-2;
    count_2++;
}
while(valor>=1){
    valor=valor-1;
    count_1++;
}
while(valor>=0.50){
    valor=valor-0.50;
    count_50cents++;
}
while(valor>=0.25){
    valor=valor-0.25;
    count_25cents++;
}
while(valor>=0.10){
    valor=valor-0.10;
    count_10cents++;
}
while(valor>=0.05){
    valor=valor-0.05;
    count_5cents++;
}
while(valor>0){
    valor=valor-0.01;
    count_1cents++;
}
printf("NOTAS:\n");
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n",count_100);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n",count_50);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n",count_20);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n",count_10);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n",count_5);
printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n",count_2);
printf("MOEDAS:\n");
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n",count_1);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n",count_50cents);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n",count_25cents);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n",count_10cents);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n",count_5cents);
printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n",count_1cents);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jovem, Onde você está setando a variável *valor*? Perceba que você tenta ler ela no trecho scanf("%f",&valor); mas não possui essa variável. Tente declarar e veja se resolve, vamos falando :)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘int’)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/336609/invalid-operands-to-binary-have-float-and-int)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma variável do tipo `double` para armazenar um valor de ponto flutuante e fazer sua leitura com [`scanf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) usando o especificador de formato [`%lf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string), veja só:

```
double valor;
scanf("%lf",&valor);
```

Por fim, seu ultimo loop `while()`, responsável por fazer a contagem das moedas de `1 centavo`, está incorreto e deveria ser algo do tipo:

```
while( valor >= 0.01 ){
    valor=valor-0.01;
    count_1cents++;
}
```

Dessa forma, o algoritmo vai considerar entradas contendo valores até a "casa" dos centavos, arredondando sempre para "baixo" caso haja alguma fração de centavo na entrada digitada, por exemplo:

```
123.123
NOTAS:
1 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Arredondou para `123.12`, ignorou `0.003`.

Ou:

```
999.999
NOTAS:
9 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
2 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
2 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
4 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```

Arredondou para `999.99`, ignorou `0.009`.

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei alguns erros no seu código, o arrumei e funcionou perfeitamente, primeiro você esta declarando valores inteiros em vez de flutuantes, no scanf você esta pedindo o valor da variável "valor", mas você não declarou essa variável e sim "valor 1 e valor 2", segue abaixo o código arrumado, testei o mesmo aqui e funcionou.

```
int main (){
float valor;
//o mesmo vale para outras variaveis(altere de int para float.)
scanf("%f",&valor);
//para valores flutuantes utiliza-se %f para receber os valores.
```

lá em baixo também altere os printfs para (%.0f), assim você estará declarando os valores flutuantes e dizendo que não quer nenhuma casa na decimal.

restante esta igual.