# invalid operands to binary % (have ‘float’ and ‘int’)

Tags: c, int, float

Quando compilo o código obtenho o erro no titulo da pergunta para a linha `res100=notas%100;`

Como resolver ?

Código:

```
      float notas,N100,M1,M050,M025,M010,M005,M001,res100,res2,res1,res05,res025,res010,res005,res001,N50,N20,res20,N10,res10,N5,res5,N2;
  scanf("%f",&notas );
  if ((notas>0)&&(notas<1000000.00));
  {
    N100=(notas/100);
    res100=notas%100;
    N50=(res100/50);
    res50=res100%50;
    N20=(res50/20);
    res20=res50%20;
    N10=(res20/10);
    res10=res20%10;
    N5=(res10/5);
    res5=res10%5;
    N2=(res5/2);
    res2=res5%2;
    M1=(res2/1);
    res1=res2%1
    M050=(res1/0.50);
    res050=res1%0.50;
    M025=(res050/0.25);
    res025=res050%0.25;
    M010=(res025/0.10);
    res010=res025%0.10;
    M005=(res010/0.05);
    res005=res010%0.05;
    M001=(res005/0.01);
    printf("NOTAS:\n");
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", N100);
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", N50);
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", N20);
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", N10);
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", N5);
    printf("%.2f nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", N2);
    /*MOEDAS*/
    printf("MOEDAS\n");
    printf("%.2f moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n%.2f moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n
    %.2f moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n
    %.2f moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n
    %.2f moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n
    %.2f moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n",M1,M050,M025,M010,M005,M001);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não pode utilizar o operador modulo (resto da divisão inteira), o `%`, entre um `float` e um `int` que é o que acontece aqui:

```
float notas...;
res100 = notas % 100;
// float --^      ^---int
```

Ou altera o `notas` para inteiro ou efetua a  operação no domínio dos floats através da função [`fmod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/):

```
res100 = fmod(notas, 100);
```

Para o código que tem de calcular o troco, o ideal é tratar tudo como inteiros, como se a unidade fosse centimos, e como se tudo estivesse multiplicado por 100, para evitar problemas de precisão que surgem quando lida com floats. Desta forma não irá precisar de usar `fmod` e o operador modulo normal irá ser suficiente.